# Greek text writing problem

Tags: php, html

i am working on php. in my index.php page i have included right.php. right.php contains greek text. index.php has the html headers. the greek text are not showing correctly. when i open the right.php file in dreamweaver and save the page, it gives warning about the text. what can i do to solve this? because right.php has common contents which is used in many pages.

Comment: First off, I would suggest reading Joel's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is all to do with the content type of your pages. Most likely you are trying to save / display the text in latin1 format which doesn't support the characters you are trying to display.

The most sensible thing to do is convert everything to UTF-8. If you're manually editing the text then ensure your text editor (i.e. Dreamweaver) is set to save the files as UTF-8 and then ensure you have the following meta tag on your page

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are saving your files as UTF-8 encoding (check preferences in DreamWeaver to find file encoding).  Also make sure your HTML `<head>` tags include charset similar to this: `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

You can use a different character set if you prefer, but UTF-8 supports the entire Unicode character space, so it's pretty safe.

Comment: never write tag name in uppercase

Answer (score 0):

You have to set file encoding to `utf-8` and set it also in `<meta>` charset tag in `<head>` HTML.